# Checking for Obstacle in Path / Shortest Path

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I am working on a simulated robotics program (using the Morse-robot simulator), which involves controlling a robot to move around a room (using spoken language) with various boxes, other objects, and other robots. I'd like the robot to:
1. Avoid obstacles (boxes, other robots)
2. Find the shortest path

For now, I'm ignoring the problem of dynamic obstacles, such as other robots constantly changing position, though that'll certainly come into play eventually.

I am aware of A* search and Dijkstra's Algorithm, and have implemented similar graph-search algorithms in the past; however, these procedures involve a graph/grid search. Currently, the robot's world model is represented by a dictionary of objects within the world, as opposed to a tile-based grid that indicates whether certain tiles are filled or not. E.g.:

{Box={position: (3, 4)...}, Robot={position: (0,0)...}}

If necessary, I could go through the process of changing the world model to a grid/graph representation, but it seems to me that shouldn't be necessary. For shortest-path, the Morse simulator will move the "crow's distance" from Point A to Point B - ploughing right through any obstacles in the way.

Thus, what I'd like to add is a control feature that checks if any obstacles are in the current path between the robot and its destination, and if so, suggests an alternative, N-part route.

What I've implemented so far, in Python, simply checks whether an object falls within a range of the slope between Point A and Point B:

```
def check_for_obstacles(origin, destination):
     slope = get_slope(origin, destination)
     obstacles = []
     initialX = origin[0]
     for obj in world:
          worldObj = getattr(world, obj)
          pos = [worldObj.pos.x, worldObj.pos.y]
          yInt = slope * pos[0] + origin[1]
          diff = abs(pos[1] - yInt)
          if diff < 2: # Hard-coded footprint of object, for now
              obstacles.append(obj)
     return obstacles
```

In a few test-cases, this seems to work. Presumably, once I get a list of obstacles in the path, I'll find some triangulation for a new path, and then continually check the obstacles as I go. Does this seem like a reasonable solution, or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: are you obstacles points?

Comment: Yep, they are just points in a list. The list contains the "center" of the object, so I project a footprint around them when checking if a point collides with an obstacle.